# How to get the contacts programmatically using MonoTouch c#?

Tags: c#, iphone, xamarin.ios, contacts

How to get the contacts in iPhone? I need to get all attributes from iPhone contacts. How to achieve programmatically using MonoTouch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ABAddressBook](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Comment: How to get the Address from contact? i got all values from contact. But i cant get the Address.

Answer (score 4):

```
ABAddressBook iPhoneAddressBook = new ABAddressBook();

ABPerson[] Contacts = iPhoneAddressBook.GetPeople();

foreach (ABPerson item in Contacts) {

    ABMultiValue<NSDictionary> Contact  = item.GetPhones();

    foreach (ABMultiValueEntry<NSDictionary> cont in Contact) {
                // cont.Label  indicates the type ( home,work,etc)
        // get the contact via cont.Value

    } 
}
```