# Edit ABPeoplePickerNavigationController navigationbar button

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

```
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController _contactController;

    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        _contactController = new ABPeoplePickerNavigationController();

        //viewController = new HomeScreen ();
        //navController = new UINavigationController (_contactController);
        window.RootViewController = _contactController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
```

so now when the app opens the contact list is displayed. I want to put a different functionality to the rightnavigationbar Button instead of the cancel? How do i do this? how to get access to this button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` control couldn't be modified without finding right subviews in it's view. Moreover, app with such modifications could be denied by Apple.

Try to make your own `UIViewController`, which functionality will be close to `iOS`s `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`:

- Read contacts via [`AddressBook`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5674914/548395) class;
- Pass contact data into `UITableView` with sections and indexes.

Comment: But then the UI is affected.This also becomes a lengthy process.Any other solution for this?

Comment: This is true. Making your own dialog is a bit harder and longer process. Yet it will be 100% flexible in future and will be App Store compatible.

Comment: There should be another way to change the navigationitem control or access the navigation item so that on that click i can add another view and this is done in objective-c.The contacts app has this functionality which directs it to a new view which is for "add new contact".

Comment: Seems like it's not possible. I'd tried to subclass `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` and change properties of it's `NavigationItem` and `NavigationController.NavigationItem` - unfortunately, nothing had changed.

Comment: References: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688072/how-can-i-change-the-look-of-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-so-that-i-can-se, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362936/customized-abpeoplepickernavigationcontroller-like-viber-whatsapp I'm sorry.